# Figure next to list (caption problems)

Tags: floats, captions, floatrow, chemstyle

I am trying to put a figure next to a list, where the list is talking about the figure. This is fine, I can do that with the minipage environment. However, my problem is that when I try to put a caption on the figure, it captions the entire "figure" containing the minipages, not just the picture itself. I have included an example of what I have done.

I have searched around on the internet but haven't been able to work out a solution. I have tried using subfigures, wrapping text, floatinf figure, etc. None of these have worked, often giving an output with the figure in the wrong place.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Here is my document so far:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[ignorefoot, ignoremp, ignorehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eepic}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemstyle}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{./Scripts/simplemargins}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
        \begin{itemize} [ ] % To get list without points
            \item{Blah blah blah
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item{Text}
                    \item{Text}
                \end{enumerate}
            }
            \item{More blah blah blah
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item{Text}
                    \item{Text}
                \end{enumerate}
            }
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{caption_example.pdf}
        \caption{default}
        \label{fig:label}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[Example output](http://imageupload.org/?di=1012971581029)

Comment: Hi @anpro, welcome to tex.sx. Can you please add a full [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/1235) including the class and the packages you load? **It works just fine with just `article` class and `graphicx` loaded.** You seem to load some package which changes the caption (and `itemize` because the normal one doesn't like the `[]` argument).

Comment: @anpro: Could you include your preamble as well? I could not reproduce the issue with the documentclass `article` and the packages `{enumitem}` and `[demo]{graphicx}`.

Comment: Hi. I added in my preamble, and also tried to put in an example output, but couldn't due to my rep not being high enough. I used the `paralist` package to alter the `itemize` environment.

Comment: @anpro: One way to fix this kind of things is to **minimise** the code, i.e. remove unrelated packages, text and macros, until the error disappears. Then the last thing removed most likely caused the issue. From that point it is much easier to troubleshoot, e.g. to have a peak in the manual of that package.

Comment: I just did that and it seems to be the chemstyle package that is causing the problems.

Comment: The package in question is `chemstyle`. It modifies the caption format causing this. It loads the `caption` package but I couldn't find the cause to give you a solution which counts as answer here. @anpro

Comment: @Martin: chemstyle calls the package floatrow. I think p.14 of the manual of floatrow partially answers.

Comment: I've deleted the migrated version of this question as this seems to be the one that everyone is concentrating on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the chemstyle package with option `floatrow` (to make sure the floatrow package will be used by the chemstyle package) and put a `\RawFloats` as first command inside the figure:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % option "demo" added for compiling without images
\usepackage[floatrow]{chemstyle}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\RawFloats
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
        \begin{itemize} [ ] % To get list without points
            \item{Blah blah blah
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item{Text}
                    \item{Text}
                \end{enumerate}
            }
            \item{More blah blah blah
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item{Text}
                    \item{Text}
                \end{enumerate}
            }
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{caption_example.pdf}
        \caption{default}
        \label{fig:label}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

(The `\RawFloats` command is described in the floatrow package documentation.)

Comment: @anpro: This is a much better way of fixing the problem (from the [`floatrow` documentation](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/floatrow/floatrow.pdf): "If you want LATEX behavior just for one environment, input a \RawFloats command inside environment"). You should probably accept Axel's answer instead of mine.

Answer (score 2):

As Martin suggested in the comments, minimizing the code often helps (that's why it's called a minimal example :)

You've added two `\usepackage{graphix}` to your preamble, this seems too much. And to reproduce your problem, all the chemical packages seem too much too.

If I minimize your example, I don't see a problem with the code, as you can see in [this screenshot](http://cl.ly/4Shb).

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
        \begin{itemize}[ ] % To get list without points
            \item{Blah blah blah
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item{Text}
                    \item{Text}
                \end{enumerate}
            }
            \item{More blah blah blah
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item{Text}
                    \item{Text}
                \end{enumerate}
            }
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{caption_example.pdf}
        \caption{default}
        \label{fig:label}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

With your code I cannot seem to compile the document when I have `\usepackage{chemstyle}` turned on, so this might be the first package to look at.

Additionally I don't have access to `%\usepackage{./Scripts/simplemargins}`. Looking at the name, I suggest this `simplemargins` might be the culprit. Maybe it's doing something weird with the margin which influences the caption...

Comment: @anpro: Sorry, I didn't see your reply above while typing my answer. Glad Martins comment worked worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround for how the `chemstyle` package takes control of the caption placement is to not use a `figure` environment for the list and figure, and generate the caption using

`\captionof{figure}{<caption>}`

instead of

`\caption{<caption>}`

With this method, the construct will no longer float, which may or may not be acceptable for you.

---

Another way would be to use a `subfloat` with the subcaption redefined to look like a normal figure caption:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[ignorefoot, ignoremp, ignorehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eepic}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemstyle}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{./Scripts/simplemargins}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font=normalsize,labelformat=simple}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{Figure \arabic{figure}:}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
        \begin{itemize} [ ] % To get list without points
            \item{Blah blah blah
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item{Text}
                    \item{Text}
                \end{enumerate}
            }
            \item{More blah blah blah
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item{Text}
                    \item{Text}
                \end{enumerate}
            }
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
\subfloat[default]{
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{caption_example.pdf}
        \label{fig:label}}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That worked great. Thanks for your help Jake.